# What do you call a person who is different from the people in his community

Tags: personification

When we look at a particular community we have a sort of opinion about the people of that community . There are sevaral things which sort of generalise people from a community or caste like whether they are introverts,extroverts,fun loving,drink too much, high on life and even their skin tone etc.What do you call a person who is different from the people in his community ?

Comment: I'm not sure there will be a single word that covers all kinds of differences between a member and a community. Can you be more specific about what kinds of differences you care about? Especially, does the community still accept the person despite their difference?

Comment: There's the informal (and only mildly pejorative) "odd man out".

Comment: *deviant*, *abnormal* (in other words, a human being)

Comment: Is *outsider* not adequate for the situation?

Comment: @Blckknght Yes the community accepts the person. A person who has no problem with the ideas or the people of his community but he/she is different from them. Would be ok if you consider the first four differences i've mentioned.

Comment: @tobybot No,not really ... the closest word i've got from the answers till now is unconventional.

Comment: One more suggestion: iconoclast? Edit to clarify: while the dictionary definition is all about the destruction of things seen as unnecessary or whatever, I think colloquial use puts it more at "person who breaks social norms"

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  It would seem to me, though, that the people in a community are unlikely to be similar in personality, whether or not they drink, and so forth.  So how can a person be different from all of them, when they cannot all be alike?

Comment: Different, alien, unique, uncharacteristic, strange, outlier.  Etc.  Thesaurus will probably have more than come to me as I type.

Comment: [black sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_sheep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their folks would consider them [**"eccentric"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eccentric) or [**"unconventional"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconventional)

> - eccentric - "one that deviates markedly from an established norm, especially a person of odd or unconventional behavior."
> - unconventional - "not conventional :  not bound by or in accordance with convention :  being out of the ordinary"

If you are looking for a somewhat depreciative term, **"a weirdo"** might fit.  Then again, if the person has telents and is admired, **"a breed apart"** comes to mind.

> - [**a breed apart**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20breed%20apart) - "more special than others of the same kind"

Answer (score 2):

**Outlier** covers your request well, and I'd argue it's not (yet?) considered a pejorative.

It's commonly used in statistics to describe a data point outside the norm, but it also can describe people who because of location, physical differences, beliefs, or other traits would be considered different from the rest of the group that they are in.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outlier defs 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

You may be served by the word [***nonconformist***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonconformist).

> 2 A person who does not conform to prevailing ideas or practices in their behaviour or views.
> *‘Jenkins was a nonconformist who disdained the rugby union coaching certificate’
>
> ‘she was a nonconformist, an individualist’*

(To address WS2'comment: Note that *dissenter* is a separate, different meaning of the same word.)

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonconformist

Comment: The problem is that "non-conformist" has a very specific meaning in Britain, especially historically. "Non-conformists" were (and still are, though the term is far less used) those protestants who were not Anglican communicants (Church of England members). And since you mention rugby, I assume you belong to a country where the Anglican (or Scottish Presbyterian) church has a leading role (unless you are Irish, French, Italian or Argentinian?)  I would never use the word "non-conformist" to mean anything other than that. A better one would be *individualist*.

Comment: American English does not carry the same religious connotation.

Comment: @Rache In America would you ever talk about "segregating" people, e.g. children into ability groups? My guess is that a word like "segregation" would be avoided like the plague because of its historic resonance. "Non-conformist" is not at all like that - there is nothing insulting about calling someone a "non-conformist" - but because of its specific meaning it would simply be avoided for other purposes.

Comment: @WS2 actually I'm referring to the _other_ meaning that nonconformist has. There are two.

Comment: @ws2 When it was still practiced, segregating students into classes based on reading levels or test scores was called "tracking."